# How to set the hAxis interval with Google Visualization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I have used Google visualization to display the chart, however when I get multiple rows of the data-table it makes my chart looks messy, so how can I set the horizontal axis interval when there are many columns of data?

Example: I have the range of horizontal axis for each month but actually I want to set the horizontal axis range in every three months.

Comment: You cannot specify an interval, but, assuming your chart uses a "date" type column and not a "string" type column for the months, you can use the `hAxis.gridlines.count` or `hAxis.ticks` options to specify the number of labels or specify which axis values should be labeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [d3 time intervals](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) to generate clean ticks for you on a Google Chart.

`d3.time.intervals` will generate a list that you can pass in to the `hAxis.ticks` option.

For example:

```
ticks = d3.time.months(
    new Date(2013, 5, 1),  // start
    new Date(2014, 2, 1),  // stop
    3)                     // step

// Set chart options
var options = {
    title: 'your data',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    hAxis: {ticks: ticks}
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S7ETx/2/

[image: Graph with 3-monthly ticks]